# Using C# to program a zaber stage but getting null variable error in my code for "var speed"

Tags: c#, zaber

```
    using System;
    using Zaber.Motion;
    using Zaber.Motion.Ascii;
    namespace ZaberMotion
    {

    class Program
     {
    static Axis x_axis;
    static Device device1;
   
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Library.EnableDeviceDbStore();

        using (var connection = Connection.OpenSerialPort("COM3"))
        {
            var deviceList = connection.DetectDevices();
            Console.WriteLine($"Found {deviceList.Length} devices.");
            


            var speed = x_axis.Settings.Get("maxspeed",Units.Velocity_MillimetresPerSecond);

            Console.WriteLine("Maximum speed [mm/s]: {0}", speed);

            x_axis.Settings.Set("maxspeed", speed /9.0,Units.Velocity_MillimetresPerSecond);

            }
         }
       }
      }
```

I am getting a null value for var speed. Simple mistake I am unsure how to fix. Any tips? The initializing of the device and all is successful

Comment: Does x_axis have a value?

Comment: it is my axis of movement on my linear stage

Comment: *Should* it be that, or does it actually *have* a non null value?

Comment: My x_axis is my position and can hold many values

Comment: That is the *meaning* of your x_axis, but did you assign a value to it? I cannot see that in your posted code. And by value I don't mean "x=10", but an instance of Axis

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the device and axis before you can get the setting for the axis.

after:

```
var deviceList = connection.DetectDevices();
Console.WriteLine($"Found {deviceList.Length} devices.");
```

include:

```
device1 = deviceList[0];
x_axis = device1.GetAxis(1);
```

---

Mike McDonald

Zaber Technologies

mike@zaber.com